# Possible to generate html/text/web version of calendar for sharing?

Tags: email, ms-office, calendar

My work uses Microsoft Exchange for our mail system. I've been using Outlook for Mac 2011. Occasionally tried Mail.

One feature I really miss from Outlook for Windows is the ability to paste my calendar (html code) into an email. This makes scheduling meetings so nice since the other person can see when I'm free. If the other person is on Outlook they can look up my schedule, but many people aren't using Outlook. I also know that it's possible to set up a website of one's calendar, but this feature is disabled in my Outlook version (my work does not support this feature).

What options are there to share my calendar using my Mac? I'm willing to consider other software/websites/etc. to easily share my calendar with non-Outlook people, but I would like to stick with our exchange server.

Answer (score 3):

## PDF

You can easily create a PDF of your calendar and attach that PDF file:

1. Open Calendar.app and go to the right date on your calendar
2. 'File' -> 'Print' (or <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>)
3. Select your settings and press 'Continue'
4. Press the button in the lower left corner that says 'PDF'
5. Now you can 'Save as PDF' or 'Email PDF'

## PNG

You can also make a quick and dirty screenshot of your calendar:

1. Open Calendar.app and go to the right date on your calendar
2. Press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>, now release the keys and press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>. Now a camera icon appears.
3. Click on your calendar once using the camera icon. A screenshot will be saved on your Desktop which you can attach to your email.

Answer (score 1):

Using Outlook 2011 you can generate a synoptic calendar using print function (listed into File menu) and saving it like a PDF. Now you can share your calendar via email, if you don't want to provide a calendar subscription.

Another solution is to link your calendar inside Calendar Mac OS X application, and after this share the calendar or generate a synoptic calendar always using print function.

In both case you can keep using your Microsoft Exchange server and mail system.